# Button goes back to original style after click instead of staying active

Tags: css

Basically I have two three styles for a button: normal, hover and active.

Once the button is clicked I want it to stay with the active style instead of going back to normal for a brief moment before the page loads. Can this be done with css or do I have to do it with jquery?

Comment: You'll have to use javascript to add a class to that button, or modify its style directly when it is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use the `:focus` pseudo-class instead of `:active`, as `:active` only applies as long as the mouse is down on an element, whereas clicking on said element will give it `:focus` until that focus is transferred elsewhere (like another button on your page, or another window entirely).